# PYGTK Resizing permissions

Tags: python, resize, pygtk

I want to set a window's size, and then be able to resize it while the program is running. I've been able to make the window large, but I can't resize it smaller than the original set size. For a different project, I would also like to know how to make it so the window is not resizable at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question: `Gtk.Window.resize(width, height)` should work. If you use `set_size_request(width, height)`, you cannot resize your window smaller than these values.

For the second question: `Gtk.Window.set_resizable(False)`

Comment: Short, direct and effective: +1